# change pageid or create new page for an old pageid in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Background: In short I've make an error and I have an external link to http://www.mysite.com/?page_id=7, but the page is not there, show showing up with a 404 error.

Question: What is the fastest way of getting a page that I can use to appear for this URL?

Notes:

- I've got access to the DB and see the data via "select ID, post_title, post_name, post_status from wp_gkpfxa_posts;" Could make updates if I could confirm what is required.
- from db

  mysql> select ID, post_title, post_name, post_parent, post_status from wp_gkpfxa_posts;

> ```
> +----+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
> | ID | post_title                                   | post_name                                    | post_parent | post_status |
> +----+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
> |  2 | Sample Page                                  | sample-page                                  |           0 | trash       |
> |  7 | Sample Page                                  | 2-revision-v1                                |           2 | inherit
> ```
>
> |

- This sample page is not showing, so I assume I deleted it initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way imho would be a custom .htaccess mod_rewrite rule that points to whatever you want it to.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=7
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?page_id=43 [NC,L]
```

Comment: haven't quite got this working so created this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203009/is-this-htaccess-section-correct  (i.e. for your thinking out the box solution :))